# Wordpress deny access to wp-admin directory in Apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

What i am trying to do is to deny access to wp-admin (users can login) and allow access only from specific ip.

I put these to .htaccess but i get 500 Internal server error:

```
# BEGIN Custom rules
<Directory /wp-admin>
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from x.x.x.x
</Directory>

# END Custom rules
```

Comment: try changing deny/allow order to  `Order allow, deny` and put `Allow from x.x.x.x` in front of `Deny from all`

Comment: also, what version of apache are you running? I believe the authorisation directives are different for Apache v2.4

Comment: No, it dosen't work. Apache version is 2.2.15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put below into `.htaccess` file, and place it under `wp-admin` folder

```
# BEGIN Custom rules
<LIMIT GET>
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  # whitelist IP address
  Allow from x.x.x.x
</LIMIT>

# END Custom rules
```

Comment: This is working. But the whitelist isn't working. I am using ssh to connect to other server with putty. I use localhost and port 8888 but when i put that to the browser it redirects to the site's url.